# Nested IF ELSE in a derived column

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl, derived-column

I have the following logic to store the date in BI_StartDate as below:

- If `UpdatedDate` is not null then `BI_StartDate=UpddatedDate`
- ELSE `BI_StartDate` takes `EntryDate` value , if the `EntryDate` is null
  then `BI_StartDate=CreatedDate`
- If the `CreatedDate` IS NULL then `BI_StartDate=GetDATE()`

I am using a derived column as seen below:

```
ISNULL(UpdatedDateODS)  ? EntryDateODS : (ISNULL(EntryDateODS) ? CreatedDateODS :
(ISNULL(CreatedDateODS) ? GETDATE()  ))
```

I am getting this error:

> The expression "ISNULL(UpdatedDateODS)  ? EntryDateODS :
>   (ISNULL(EntryDateODS) ? CreatedDateODS :(ISNULL(CreatedDateODS) ?
>   GETDATE()  ))" on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column
>   Output].Columns[Derived Column 1]" is not valid.

Comment: Does `BI_StartDate` means _"Date de bon d'intervention"_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking the first non-null which is a coalesce which doesn't exist in SSIS Data Flow (derived Column).

I'd suggest a very simple script component:

```
Row.BIStartDate = Row.UpdateDate ?? Row.EntryDate ?? Row.CreatedDate ?? DateTime.Now;
```

This is the Input Columns Screen:

[image]

This is the Inputs and Outputs:

[image]

And then you add the above code to Row Processing section:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        /*
         * Add your code here
         */

        Row.BIStartDate = Row.UpdateDate ?? Row.EntryDate ?? Row.CreatedDate ?? DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: I will be waiting thank you in advance. Can you explain more why it is not possible to use Derived column ?

Comment: BTW -> The code will take the first non-null value as the result. You can rearrange the order, but that is what I got out of your if then else logic.

Answer (score 1):

From **syntax perspective**, the nested if-else condition is not written well, since you have to make sure that all possible output should have the same data type, also you didn't mentioned the last "else" condition:

```
ISNULL(UpdatedDateODS)  ? EntryDateODS : (ISNULL(EntryDateODS) ? CreatedDateODS :
(ISNULL(CreatedDateODS) ? GETDATE() : **<missing>** ))
```

From **logical perspective**, you the expression may throw exception since you are using `EntryDateODS` column if `ISNULL(UpdatedDateODS)` is true, while you should check if `EntryDateODS` is not null before using it, I suggest that the expression is as following:

```
ISNULL(UpdatedDateODS)  ? UpdatedDateODS : (ISNULL(EntryDateODS) ? EntryDateODS :
(ISNULL(CreatedDateODS) ? CreatedDateODS : GETDATE()  ))
```

As mentioned above, if `UpdatedDateODS` , `EntryDateODS`, `CreatedDateODS` and `GETDATE()` **don't have the same data type** then you should cast to a unified data type as example:

```
ISNULL(UpdatedDateODS)  ? (DT_DATE)UpdatedDateODS : (ISNULL(EntryDateODS) ? (DT_DATE)EntryDateODS :
(ISNULL(CreatedDateODS) ? (DT_DATE)CreatedDateODS : (DT_DATE)GETDATE()  ))
```